# Uploading APK file error "You need to add an icon to your APK"

Tags: android

I am using Eclipse - I export my project and sign it. But then I get this error.

[SO] Won't let me upload the screen shot

The error is "Upload Failed: You need to add an icon to your APK"

I have files named icon.png in all of my drawables folders. And I am not sure what is causing this error.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" >
```

ic_launcher is my icon in all of my drawable folders

Edit for clarification:
In my manifest I have the above code. 
In all my drawable folders I have my icon png called ic_launcher (I also added icon.png when the upload failed the first time)

Comment: Post your manifest xml. Does it have the `android:icon="@drawable/your_icon"` attribute in the root of `<application>`? Also, you can link to images, usually someone with more rep will embed it for you if it's on imgur.

Comment: In my case, adding a missing icon attribute in <application element fixed this. (though my MAIN activity was having an icon attribute, but seems Google Play looks for application's icon attribute only.

Answer (score 4):

Your icon needs to be named: "ic_launcher.png" not icon.png.  Or you can change your manifest to point to whatever  you want the drawable named.

Answer (score 2):

By using this line

```
 android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

Android is expecting to find an icon named "ic_launcher.something" where something is a valid image format such as .png or .jpg

You mention your icon is called "icon.png"

Change one or the other and it should work.

Comment: Figured it out - Should have uploaded my entire manifest. I accidentily had two <application> nodes in my manifest

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem. i know it says you need to add an icon but try to check the @string/app_name. if your app_name has "\n" in it, remove it, rebuild and upload your apk again. that's what happened in my case.

[You need to add an icon to your APK while uploading App to google play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644711/you-need-to-add-an-icon-to-your-apk-while-uploading-app-to-google-play)

hopefully, this help other people too.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem. Problem is resolved now.

- Please make sure you have icon with .png file extension.
- See if there is not any mismatch for the icon in the file name or extension in following folders mdpi xdpi ldpi etcv folders.
- If you do not require multiple folders you can remove them.

I hope above points will resolve your issue.