# You need to add an icon to your APK while uploading App to google play

Tags: android, google-play

I dont know where i am going wrong . I need to upload APK to google play and whenever i am trying to upload it , it is showing an error message as displayed in the attached screenshot. The error is that " You need to add an icon to your APK " but for sure i have already added an icon to my APk in my manifest file . I dont what it is asking for whether it is error because of icon resolution or there is something i am lacking with . pls help .[image]

Comment: What's your icon filename? And what's the icon filename specified in your manifest? Do the two match?

Comment: Show us the relevant part of your manifest file, and also tell us the names and locations of the icons in your `res` folder.

Comment: you should have an icon of 512*512 size....

Comment: @VikramSingh no, launcher icon sizes are described here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html

Comment: this is my manifest file    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
         <activity android:name=".SplashScreen"
                  android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: i have got four drawable folders in my resources viz. drawable, drawable-hdpi,drawable-mdpi,drawable-ldpi . All these folders contain icon.png file as mentioned in my manifest file

Comment: Have you tried making use of the default ic_launcher instead? If it works, then you will be sure the problem is your custom icon and nothing else...

Comment: try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61380910/2261211

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is likely that in your manifest that you do not have an icon defined or are referencing an image that does not exist.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem make sure that you don't have \n in the name of your application

Comment: you're a hero, really

Comment: @user1634451: sorry, I am unable to get it. Can you please explain?

Comment: @MiteshShah if you have a new line character in the application name google doesn't let you upload it

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But, there is not new line character in app name. It's just a single word. Still I am facing this issue.

Comment: Is there any special characters in your app name?

Answer (score 4):

The same problem but in my case I was missing "android:icon" attribute in application element, note I had it only in activity.

```
<application ... android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <activity ... android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
```

Answer (score 2):

After long and painful search, found that ApplicationAttributes in Manifest file was empty, inspite of mentioning android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" in AndroidManifest.xml.

Filling up ApplicationAttributes solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

remove \n from your application name