# Can we upload .apk file without launcher icon on Google Market ?

Tags: android, google-play

My application do not have launcher icon. Can I upload the apk to market or is it compulsory to have launcher icon in apk ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Launcher icon` is the icon that is shown on your device's launcher. And your app may not have any entry point for user, so such icon is not mandatory. However if you refer to the icon you need to upload to Google Play - then yes you have to have it. And people usually put `Launcher icon` here as they have it already

Answer (score 1):

You need to have some sort of icon, even if it's a default, but if you're uploading to the Play Store, you definitely want an icon so that users can identify your app.

Comment: we(my firm) have a couple of applications in market and I want to launch my application through one of the existing app only, and hence I don't want launcher icon.

Is there any work around for it ?

Answer (score 1):

You CANNOT upload the apk to market without icon. So yes it is compulsory.

[You need to add an icon to your APK while uploading App to google play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644711/you-need-to-add-an-icon-to-your-apk-while-uploading-app-to-google-play)

Comment: we(my firm) have a couple of applications in market and I want to launch my application through one of the existing app only, and hence I don't want launcher icon.

Is there any work around for it ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by launching an application through existing app. Every app in the market is unique, and the only thing you can do is push updates to the already released apps. You CANNOT replace an existing app entirely with different package identifiers. Also, every existing app can only be updated with the original signature that was used to sign the first release.

The only "way", i guess, is release an "update" for one of the those apps you've published in the market, meaning with the same package id and incrementing the versionCode and versionName, like an update.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. My question is answered by Marcin Orlowski. :)