# Android app beta testing rollout vs Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

[image]

In my company we create android app for our client and give them *.apk file to publish it to play store. This time they're getting an [issue like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644711/you-need-to-add-an-icon-to-your-apk-while-uploading-app-to-google-play) . So we were thinking to come up with a solution to upload a test app to test app market which will be exact replica of app store. So that we can see if the app can be uploaded properly to app market before we hand the apk to our client. Just found out they have some thing call [Beta-testing and staged rollouts](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en) which will do as we were expecting to do. But i am not sure if i do upload the test apk here, does it gonna create any issue about uploading the app in real app store as real app will be uploaded by our client company. I read article about saying changing package and app name might help but still dont want to take any chance.  I will appreciate any prompt answer as i have to figure out this by this week. Thanks in advance for any solution or work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check AndroidMainfeast.xml file for proper [permission.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html) 
Changing the permission helped us to upload the app to play store.