# where to place 512x512 launcher icon for google play

Tags: android, android-assets

I've used [Launcher Icon Generator](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-launcher.html) to generate a simple icon. It also generates web_hi_res_512.png which is, as far I know, required size of launcher icon for publishing app at Google Play. But where should be this icon placed?

Comment: It is not part of your .apk, but you need to separately upload it in the developer console as part of the store listing.

Comment: It's possible, but I have problem to upload release.apk. It ends up with "You need to add an icon to your APK.", checked related questions, no luck though. This just came to my mind, as a possible issue.

Comment: Do you have `<activity android:icon="@drawable/smallPic" .../>` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`? Furthermore, in the developer console, you must select that 512x512 image under the "High res icon" section.

Comment: I have there android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher", works while testing on device (debug.apk)...

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644711/you-need-to-add-an-icon-to-your-apk-while-uploading-app-to-google-play

Comment: Have checked, no \n in label, recommended prefix "ic_launcher" used, at least it seems that missing 512x512 launcher icon does not cause "You need to add an icon to your APK." problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In [Google Play App Publish](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/) interface:
 -> All Applications -> $YOURAPP -> Store Listing

There is `High-res Icon *` 512 x 512 32-bit PNG